# .env calling variables in different files

Tags: javascript, node.js, dotenv

I have a .env file that stores two different variables:

```
x=123
y=456
```

In the same folder, I have three other files, with a tree below:

```
/folder
   /.env
   /config.js
   /app_setup.js
   /match_algo.js
```

In my config.js file, I am reading the variables inside .env file and exporting them:

```
const dotenv = require('dotenv');
const cfg = {};
dotenv.config({path: '.env'});

cfg.port = process.env.PORT;
cfg.x = process.env.x;
cfg.y = process.env.y;

module.exports = cfg;
```

In the app.setup.js file, I am using the variable `x` from .env:

```
var firebase = require("firebase");
const Config = require('./config');

var config = {
  apiKey: Config.x
};
firebase.initializeApp(config);

module.exports = firebase;
```

In match_algo, I am using the variable `y` from .env to do something else:

```
const Router = require('express').Router;
const Config2 = require('./config');
const router = new Router();

exports.return_match_uid = function return_match_uid() {
  var variable2 = Config2.y;
.....
```

Apparently, the variable `y` in match_algo is not read properly. I did not see any problem with my codes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you want to give a path to dotenv config, you need to give the proper path. Not just the `.env`. See this

```
const dotenv = require('dotenv');
const cfg = {};
dotenv.config({path: './folder/.env'});

cfg.port = process.env.PORT;
cfg.x = process.env.x;
cfg.y = process.env.y;

module.exports = cfg;
```

Hope this helps

Comment: the .env file is in the same folder as config.js, I don't think this is necessary

Comment: @IsaakNewton I guess it works when the .env is at the root level. In your case it is not. Also, you are explicitly using path and since you are saying `.env` which is not where it is. It is inside the `/folder` so you need a path. i quickly created an app for this. You can access it here. https://repl.it/repls/MuddyViciousComputationalscience

at the moment it has the correct path and hence it works, if you change the path to `.env` it wouldn't work

Comment: I reworked my codes according to your answer, and it works like a charm. Thank you. What is considered root level in this case?